# gzip not working in nginx + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, gzip, passenger

I have an nginx + passenger installed on Amazon Linux EC2 server, running a Rails application. The application yields JSON responses.

The JSON response is rendered with length header:

```
# test_controller.rb
# result contains a large 400k JSON string
headers["Content-Length"] = result.size.to_s
render :json => result
```

I tried enabling gzip, but the response is still not compressed. I checked it with [GIDZipTest](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php).

```
# nginx.conf
gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_comp_level 1;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_min_length 500;
gzip_types application/x-javascript  application/json;
```

Answer (score 7):

I have it working properly, try adding (text/javascript)

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Comment: Sorry, still the same. I am sure it may help in other cases, probably something else is not configured right. If it's any help - nginx is also configured to upstream fcgi applications.

Answer (score 1):

gzip_types works! In my case, **application/javascript** also required for Ruby on Rails

```
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved. The [php script](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) is not reliable.

This is reliable:

```
wget --header="accept-encoding: gzip" URL
```

Gets the compressed version.

Testing with Chrome and Charles sniffer convinced me that everything worked fine.